# binding a variable from a yield directly to component

Tags: ember.js

I have created a component called **my-component**.
How can I have the variable `eventIsRunning` be looking at the component and not the controller of the route i'm currently in?

**app/controllers/components/my-component.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    eventIsRunning: false
});
```

**app/templates/components/my-component.hbs**

```
<form>
  {{yield}}
</form>
```

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
{{#my-component}}
   {{#if eventIsRunning}}
   {{else}}
   {{/if}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Comment: Need to keep in mind that components are unaware of anything going on outside, you have to pass eventIsRunning to it `{{#my-component eventIsRunning=eventIsRunning}}`

Comment: Components never refer directly to the controller- In your example,  the `{{#if eventIsRunning}}` is referring to the component's property unless you pass it in as @PatsyIssa mentioned.